# Как достать часть текста с разворота скана паспорта?

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, tesseract, машинное-зрение

Доброго времени суток!

Подскажите пожалуйста, в какую сторону начать думать, что бы достать ФИО со скана или фота паспорта? Я не прошу готовый код, просто не могу понять, с чего лучше начать и где порыться на эту тему. Пробовал сделать с помощью `PyTessaract` и `OpenCV`. После решения этой задачи надо будет обучить модель, распознавать нужную часть изображения и доставать эти данные.

И еще хочу спросить для специалиста какого уровня эта задача? Мне это пришло как тестовое на стажера.

P.S.: еще, по условию ТЗ, нельзя пользоваться готовыми библиотеками OCR.

Comment: Ну нихрена себе задачка. Не просто OCR написать, а ещё научить её искать текст.

Comment: Tessaract + OpenCV, одно из лучших решений. И да, модель нужно будет обучать, чтобы текст лучше распознавался + нужно будет дополнительно обрабатывать фон картинки, для еще большего результата, хотя как по мне, в стандартном варианте и так все должно работать. Ваше тестовое задание на стажера, выглядит вполне сомнительно, я бы предположил, что кантора хочет получить готовый вариант решения своей проблемы и потом сказать, что вы нам не подходите. Это можно проверить - не давать им исходный код, если они будут просить его и только его, я бы с ними дел не имел.

Comment: Кмк это уровень максимум мида по алгоритмам ОЦР, и вполне логично, если в ваши задачи входит разработка OCR, что готовыми пользоваться нельзя.... 
@Duracell вы и в правду считаете что у сеньера знакомого с алгоритмами OCR задача займет много больше суток?, что то подобное я делал для себя, но я никак не связан ни с ML ни с OCR, а ребята которые связаны делали это за ночь в одно лицо, только зада была находить не просто текст, а отслеживать определенный объект с видео потока и трекать его путь по камерам.

Comment: @Владимир Клыков, можно многое сделать, вопрос в другом, оплатят ли тебе труд...

Comment: @Duracell, вот в оплате я очень сомневаюсь, с другой стороны это хороший опыт для того у кого его вообще нет)))

Comment: А в нынешних паспортах нет машиночитаемой зоны как в загранах? А так задача решена в куче мобильных приложений, у меня даже приложение по покупке авиабилетов предложило отсканировать машиночитаемую зону вместо вбивания данных вручную

Comment: @PavelG03, ну если ради опыта, тогда можно конечно

Comment: @AlexeyTen, посмотрю про машиночитаемые зоны, спасибо. То что оно реализовано это хорошо, только вот мне это самому как то реализовать надо

Comment: Владимир Клыков вы фантазёр, не имеющий понятия о чём речь.

Comment: @Александр, поделитесь пожалуйста своим опытом

Comment: PyTesseract можно использовать?

Comment: @Александр, планирую использовать PyTesseract + OpenCV. Нельзя использовать только готовые библиотеки OCR

Comment: Размер ведь фиксированный или нет?

Comment: Тогда можно нарезать, и PyTesseract -у скормить.

Comment: @Александр, размер изображений не одинаковый, это может быть скан разворота, скан разворот+прописка, фото вместе с лицом владельца и т.д., так что просто по координатам отследить не получится))) Вот такая вот "радость". В общем я в ступоре, так и не могу разгадать эту загадку.